# Rails - 3.0.6 to 3.0.14 activerecord, multiple joins and where clause oddities

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So.. Just upgrading from 3.0.6 to 3.0.14 and one of my tests started failing badly (great!).  It pointed out (I think) that my where clause was incorrectly formed and I've just been 'getting away with it' as it were.  Just wanted to confirm (and if anyone can point me to where I can find the docs on where this change is documented).

Some code:

```
@fields = Field.joins(:region => :country).where(:regions => {:country_id => @country}).order(:name)
```

produces happy SQL

```
 "SELECT `fields`.* FROM `fields` INNER JOIN `regions` ON `regions`.`id` = `fields`.`region_id` INNER JOIN `countries` ON `countries`.`id` = `regions`.`country_id` WHERE `regions`.`country_id` = 5 ORDER BY name"
```

This query however...

```
@pools = Pool.joins(:field => {:region => :country}).where(:fields => {:regions => {:country_id => @country }},:confirmed => true).order(:leaving_date)
```

This produces ok SQL in 3.0.6

```
"SELECT `pools`.* FROM `pools` INNER JOIN `fields` ON `fields`.`id` = `pools`.`field_id` INNER JOIN `regions` ON `regions`.`id` = `fields`.`region_id` INNER JOIN `countries` ON `countries`.`id` = `regions`.`country_id` WHERE `pools`.`confirmed` = 1 AND `regions`.`country_id` = 5 ORDER BY leaving_date"
```

But in 3.0.14 it has a borked value for the country ID (seems to be the whole active record?)

```
"SELECT `pools`.* FROM `pools` INNER JOIN `fields` ON `fields`.`id` = `pools`.`field_id` INNER JOIN `regions` ON `regions`.`id` = `fields`.`region_id` INNER JOIN `countries` ON `countries`.`id` = `regions`.`country_id` WHERE `pools`.`confirmed` = 1 AND `fields`.`regions` = '--- \\n:country_id: !ruby/ActiveRecord:Country \\n  attributes: \\n    name: Test Country 1\\n    latitude: \\\"13.456\\\"\\n    created_at: 2012-06-27 10:28:46 Z\\n    updated_at: 2012-06-27 10:28:46 Z\\n    id: 2\\n    cached_slug: test-country-1\\n    longitude: \\\"46.789\\\"\\n    message: \\n    zoom: 4.0\\n' ORDER BY leaving_date"
```

Just wondering if anyone can explain what is going on here.   I suspect it should probably never have worked..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should just be

```
Pool.joins(:fields => {:region => :country}).
     where(:regions => {:country_id =>@country})
```

Just because you joined the table via another table doesn't mean that you need to do the same thing in the where clause - all you want is a condition of the form

```
regions.country_id = 1
```

This did used to work by accident, unfortunate the same accident could also allow people to inject maliciously crafted values and so was fixed in the rails 3.0.13/14 [security releases](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/6/12/ann-rails-3-0-14-has-been-released/)

As far as I know this wasn't supposed to work do there isn't really any documentation about it being removed.

Comment: Excellent! yup, I've learned a little more rails since first writing this... and so I (hope) I'd not make this mistake again!  Thanks for the clarification.  I guess what I was surprised by was that I thought with a minor version change that the api itself wasn't supposed to change.. But, as you say, it should never have worked ;)